# python attaching mailBody into the e-mail not working

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a below script which is working fine for rsync, this script actually pulling the files from the remote host(s) to the server from where its running under `dest` Folder.

However `rsync` works fine but the mail part basically the `msg = 'message + "rsync process completed"'` is not being sent as an e-mail.

Somehow i'm not to figure out what's wrong i'm doing!

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import argparse
import smtplib

#Dir Structure
dst = "/infralogs/external_dns_logs"
rsync_user = "root"
mailFrom = 'robo@helisis.com'
mailTo = 'robo@helisis.com'
mailSub = 'Rsync status'
msg = ""

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-n","--hosts",dest="hosts",help="enter remote host/hosts name, comma seperated",metavar="HOSTS")
parser.add_argument("-s","--src",dest="source",help="source file/directory",metavar="SOURCE")
parser.add_argument("-e","--exclude",dest="exclude",help="Exclude files/Directories, comma seperated list",metavar="EXCLUDE")

if len(sys.argv) < 7:
    print(len(sys.argv))
    parser.print_help()
    parser.exit()

args = parser.parse_args()

def sync(host,dst):
    exclude = ""
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.mkdir(dst)
    if ',' in args.exclude:
        for excl in args.exclude.split(','):
            exclude = exclude + " --exclude " + excl
        cmd = "rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -auPz %s %s@%s:%s %s/"%(exclude,rsync_user,host,args.source,dst)
    else:
        cmd = "rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -auPz --exclude %s %s@%s:%s %s/"%(args.exclude,rsync_user,host,args.source,dst)
    print(cmd)
    message = cmd
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
    p.wait()
    print("DONE")
    msg = message + "rsync process completed"

mailBody = "From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s" %(mailFrom,mailTo,mailSub,msg)

if ',' in args.hosts:
    for host in args.hosts.split(','):
        dest = dst + "/" + host
        sync(host,dest)
else:
    dest = dst + "/" + args.hosts
    sync(args.hosts,dest)

try:
    Mail = smtplib.SMTP('mailserver.global.helisis.com', 25, 'localhost.helisis.com')
    Mail.sendmail(mailFrom,mailTo,mailBody,msg)
    print("Mail Sent to %s" %(mailTo))
except:
    print("Mail Failed")
```

**Result output on the terminal from above script:**

> ```
> $ ./log_rsync -n remote_Server -s /var/log/infoSec/ -e "null"
>
> bind.log
>            0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=7/9)
> default.log
>        12769 100%   12.18MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=6/9)
> general.log
>         9553 100%    4.56MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=5/9)
> lame-servers.log
>          663 100%  129.49kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#4, to-check=4/9)
> network.log
>            0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#5, to-check=3/9)
> notify.log
>         3286 100%  356.55kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#6, to-check=2/9)
> queries.log
>          578 100%   47.04kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#7, to-check=1/9)
> query-errors.log
>            0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#8, to-check=0/9)
>
> sent 176 bytes  received 4303 bytes  814.36 bytes/sec
> total size is 26849  speedup is 5.99
> DONE
> Mail Sent to robo@helisis.com
> ```

Mail Service is working fine, However the `msg` variable which contains the message `msg = message + "rsync process completed"` that is not getting send rest email with subject is working, Problem looks to be with `msg` part that not being called or opened correctly.

**Just an alternative way!**

While i'm applying th below method where i have included `To` address , `Subject` and Message ie  `Rsync Process Completed Successfully.`  which works and sends an e-mail but the real question again remains same if i want to include `msg` or say want to disclose `msg` part here, how could that be done!

> ```
> EmailSender="robo@localhost.helisis.com"
> EmailReceiver="robo@helisis.com"
>
> msgBody='''From: dnsmailer <netrobo@helisis.com>
> To: To Person <robo@helisis.com>
> Subject: rsync Status from  infra-syslog
>
> Rsync Process Completed Succesfully.
> '''
>
> if ',' in args.hosts:
>     for host in args.hosts.split(','):
>         dest = dst + "/" + host
>         sync(host,dest)
> else:
>     dest = dst + "/" + args.hosts
>     sync(args.hosts,dest)
>
> try:
>     smtpobj=smtplib.SMTP('mailserver.global.helisis.com', 25, 'localhost.helisis.com')
>     smtpobj.sendmail(EmailSender,EmailReceiver,msgBody)
> except Exception as e:
>     print(e)
> ```

Comment: Hard to say without more info... What happens exactly? No mail is received? One mail is received but is does not contain what you expect? Can you ask the mail server admin for some logs to see what happens on the server?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, let me modify my post to details the information, thnx for the inputs .. though mail service is working fine, Just updated the post with details.

Comment: A *problem* is still not explicit enough. Please say exactly what you get and what you expect. I now think that the problem is not in the mailing part but I really need those detail to give you a relevant answer.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, Yes mail is working as i said, What i want is to get the `msg` part in the e-mail.

Comment: If more than one host, do you want one mail per host or one single mail with one line per host? Or could you really say (full text) WHAT YOU GET AND WHAT YOU EXPECT?

Comment: @SergeBallesta,  single mail  is enough,  I am getting only mail Subject ie `mailSub = 'Rsync status'` and i would like message contents which is  command and `"rsync process completed"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `msg` is computed inside the `sync` function (which can be called in a loop) and then just forgotten (meaning not stored).

So when you want to use it in your mail body, it is no longer available. You must use it when it is available and directly aliment the mail body, or better store it in a list and then use it to build the mail body. The code could become:

```
...
def sync(host,dst):
    ...
    message = cmd
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
    p.wait()
    print("DONE")
    return message + " rsync process completed"  # returns the msg to the caller

msglist = []             # a list to store the messages for the mail body

if ',' in args.hosts:
    for host in args.hosts.split(','):
        dest = dst + "/" + host
        msglist.append(sync(host,dest))
else:
    dest = dst + "/" + args.hosts
    msglist.append(sync(args.hosts,dest))

msg = "\n".join(msglist)                 # combine all messages, one per line
mailBody = "From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s" %(mailFrom,mailTo,mailSub,msg)

try:
    Mail = smtplib.SMTP('mailserver.global.helisis.com', 25, 'localhost.helisis.com')
    Mail.sendmail(mailFrom,mailTo,mailBody,msg)
    print("Mail Sent to %s" %(mailTo))
    Mail.bye()                  # cleaner to say goodbye to server...
    Mail.close()
except:
    print("Mail Failed")
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try sending msg using MIMEMultipart. I should work in this way.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

EmailSender = "robo@localhost.helisis.com"
EmailReceiver = "robo@helisis.com"

msgBody = '''From: dnsmailer <netrobo@helisis.com>
To: To Person <robo@helisis.com>
Subject: rsync Status from  infra-syslog

Rsync Process Completed Succesfully.
'''

try:
    Mail = smtplib.SMTP('mailserver.global.helisis.com', 25, 'localhost.helisis.com')
    mail_obj = MIMEMultipart()
    mail_obj["From"] = EmailSender
    mail_obj["To"] = EmailReceiver
    mail_obj["Subject"] = "rsync Status from  infra-syslog."
    mail_obj.preamble = "rsync Status from  infra-syslog. "
    msgBody = "Rsync Process Completed Successfully!"  # Message body
    mail_obj.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
    Mail.sendmail(from_addr=[EmailSender], to_addrs=[EmailReceiver], msg=mail_obj.as_string())
    print("Mail Sent to %s" % (EmailReceiver))
except Exception as error:
    print("Mail Failed - {}".format(error))
```

Comment: @ Vijay let me try this.

Comment: `message = "<html><h1> Hello World! </h1></html>"` here you can add your dynamic message such sync status.

Comment: Vijay,  the alternative i mentioned that works, what i would like to see is `msg = message + "rsync process completed"`  where `message` is assigned to `cmd`.
I need to include or open the `msg` variable into the message body.


even  with `MIMEMultipart` , so sending mail is not a problem, only the problem is that `msg` is not getting expanded  while sending an e-mail.

Comment: msg is not getting expanded? Would you please elaborate on that?

Comment: why are you assigning `message = "cmd"` instead of  `message = cmd`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180220/discussion-between-vijay-anand-pandian-and-pygo).

Answer (score 0):

Just taking the liberty to put the e-mail piece here which worked for me as smtplib throwing some errors which i applied earlier, below is the working e-mail portion, may be someone will be looking for same :-)

Thnx much to @Serge and @Vijay helping on this..

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib


email_sender = "syslogger@helisis.com"
email_receiver = "robo@helisis.com, robo01@helisis.com, robo02@helisis.com"


try:
    Mail = smtplib.SMTP('mailserver.global.helisis.com', 25, 'localhost.helisis.com')
    mail_obj = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    mail_obj["From"] = email_sender
    mail_obj["To"] = email_receiver
    mail_obj["Cc"] = "someone@helisis.com"
    mail_obj["Subject"] = "rsync Status from  infra-syslog."
    mail_obj.preamble = "rsync Status from  infra-syslog. "
    msgBody = "Rsync Process Completed Successfully!"  # Message body
    mail_obj.attach(MIMEText(msg, 'plain'))
    Mail.sendmail(from_addr=[email_sender], to_addrs=[email_receiver],msg=mail_obj.as_string())
    print("Mail Sent to %s" % (email_sender))
except Exception as error:
    print("Mail Failed - {}".format(error))
```