# python subprocess to capture the stdin and stdout into a variable

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, python-3.6, popen

Please note: I have a follow up question with reference to updated [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369810/python-attaching-mailbody-into-the-e-mail-not-working/52379898#52379898) here ..

Below is Just the one peice of code which i'm looking forward to trim and understand how to do it better ..

```
 import subprocess
 cmd = "rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -auPz --exclude %s %s@%s:%s %s/"%(args.exclude,rsync_user,host,args.source,dest_dir)
 cmd_content = cmd
 p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
 p.wait()
 print("DONE")
 return cmd_content + " Rsync process completed."
```

What i'm looking forward to capture the `stdout` & `stderr` from my script to be captured into a variable so, i can use and send it as an e-mail attachment.

So, refactoring the above piece here i'm importing `Popen` and `PIPE` explicitly, However,i have used `p.communicate()` as i see `Popen.communicate()` interacts with process and Send data to stdin, reads the data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached, it also waits for the process to terminate.

```
 from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
 cmd = "rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -auPz --exclude %s %s@%s:%s %s/"%(args.exclude,rsync_user,host,args.source,dest_dir)
 cmd_content = cmd
 p = Popen(cmd,stdout=PIPE,shell=True)
 p.communicate()
 print("DONE")
 return cmd_content + " Rsync process completed."
```

I see Python 2.7 onwards it also supports `subprocess.check_output()` So, we can avoid using Popen object directly and use subprocess.check_output() function to store output of a command in a string as follows but my doubt will it take in my case as i'm using `cmd` variable to pass as `shell=True`.

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> out = check_output(cmd)
```

I have looked around the subprocess examples and question around the web and SO but did not get the required information.

Comment: You don't need `p.wait()` if you call `p.communicate()`. Anyway you should probably use [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and specify `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`. Also: you do not need `shell=True` to run an `rsync` command. You could split that command line string into a list of strings and avoid `shell=True`

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta, Ah, that's pretty nice catch , i don't really need `p.wait` , i have removed that :-)

Comment: There are some major security bugs here (as in most uses of `shell=True`). Think about what happens with the name of a directory created with `mkdir $'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''` passed in (or a similarly malicious hostname or other datum). (BTW, the doubling-up is to demonstrate that the simple workaround -- just adding literal single quotes around all substitutions -- doesn't work, because literal escapes in the data can exit contexts created by such literal quotes).

Comment: Also, note that "ask a new question, don't edit your old one" is pertinent *after you already have answers*. Before a question has been answered, editing it in ways that change its meaning is still acceptable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, agreed, will give due consideration going fwd

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, i don't understood `mkdir $'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''` you conveyed into your comment , I'm agreed opening `shell=True` code becomes extremely likely to be vulnerable as shell provides the ability to pipe things around without buffering them in memory, and allows a malicious user to chain additional commands after a legitimate command is run.

Comment: @pygo, that command creates a directory named `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`. A directory with that (valid/allowable) name **cannot** be safely substituted into any command executed with `shell=True` without being escaped prior. So if you used this code to process files from a `/tmp` or uploads or incoming directory, or other untrusted source...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, understood, that's really true and in case of untrusted source it becomes highly vulnerable agreed.

Comment: To add to the previously mentioned comments (I hope I do not have a typo in there), change `cmd` definition to `cmd = ["rsync", "-e", "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-auPz", "--exclude", args.exclude, "{}@{}:{}".format(rsync_user, host, args.source), "{}/".format(dest_dir)]` and ditch the `shell=True`.

Comment: @OndrejK. thnx for the inputs, i'll look into it.